# change file path name in windows (not file name)

Tags: windows

I have a problem. Just the last few days when I change a file name, On the surface I thought that the file name was changed. However the file path name does not change.

When I try to upload to github then the file name is like it never changed.

How do you change the file path name?

EDIT

When you go to any file or directory and right click and press rename. You can rename it and then move on.

However now it seems when I rename a directory. It will show that it is renamed but if you press the properties button then it will show up with its original name and file path.

Comment: it is not clear for me what is your problem.

Comment: Are you referring to getting the actual path for net share, subst drives or UNC file paths?